# Bazel Build: Generate java classes from XSD using JAXB2

Tags: xsd, jaxb, bazel

I am new to Bazel. I want to generate Java classes from an XSD document using JaxB2.
I could not find any Java_Rule to auto-generate the classes.
Looking at [this google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/xrKf7D_nalc), a genrule with explicit command seems to generate java classes for the author.

I tried using the [github repository](https://github.com/tomask-de/bazel-xjc) suggested in the discussion but failed with `no such target '@local_jdk//:jdk-default': target 'jdk-default' not declared in package '` error.

```
➜  bazel-xjc-master bazel build //...
ERROR: /Users/<user>/bazel-xjc-master/BUILD.bazel:1:8: no such target '@local_jdk//:jdk-default': target 'jdk-default' not declared in package '' (did you mean 'jre-default'?) defined by /private/var/tmp/.../local_jdk/BUILD.bazel and referenced by '//:sample-messages'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:sample-messages' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.152s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 6 targets configured)
```

I tried searching`java_toolchain` options to handle the above error but without any success.

Is there a Bazel build example file somewhere I can look at on how to generate java classes based on an XSD file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples in the google group discussion were correct at the time, but Java toolchain integration with Bazel has changed over time, and indeed the target `@local_jdk//:jdk-default` no longer exists, and `@local_jdk//:jar` is deprecated.

But the bigger issue is that jaxb and xjc have been deprecated/removed from the jdk starting with jdk 9: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320

You'll need to get jaxb separately, something like this:

`BUILD.bazel`:

```
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "artifact")

genrule(
    name = "sample-messages",
    srcs = [
        "src/main/xsd/sample.xsd",
        "src/main/xjb/sample.xjb",
    ],
    outs = ["sample-messages.srcjar"],
    cmd = """
        mkdir sample-messages
        $(location :xjc) -quiet -d sample-messages -b $(location src/main/xjb/sample.xjb) -verbose $(location src/main/xsd/sample.xsd)
        jar cf $@ sample-messages
    """,
    exec_tools = [
        ":xjc",
    ],
)

java_binary(
    name = "xjc",
    # See bin/xjc.sh in
    # https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/3.0.2/jaxb-ri-3.0.2.zip 
    main_class = "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade",
    runtime_deps = [
        artifact("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-ri:3.0.2"),
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "sample-lib",
    srcs = [":sample-messages"],
    deps = [
        artifact("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1"),
    ]
)
```

`WORKSPACE`:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "4.2"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "cd1a77b7b02e8e008439ca76fd34f5b07aecb8c752961f9640dea15e9e5ba1ca"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)
load("@rules_jvm_external//:repositories.bzl", "rules_jvm_external_deps")
rules_jvm_external_deps()
load("@rules_jvm_external//:setup.bzl", "rules_jvm_external_setup")
rules_jvm_external_setup()

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-ri:3.0.2",
        "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1",
    ],
    # rules_jvm_external doesn't handle zip dependencies correctly, see
    # https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/issues/671
    excluded_artifacts = [
        "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-samples",
        "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-release-documentation",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)
```

`src/main/xjb/sample.xjb`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jxb:bindings version="3.0"
              xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/sample.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="org.acme.sample"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

`src/main/xsd/sample.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Sample">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
      <xs:element name="Content">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This worked really well. Thanks a lot for all your help :)

Comment: happy to help, glad it worked!